# Hide checkbox but leave it existing

Tags: javascript, grails

Hello  I have created this checkbox,how can I hide it?

```
  <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="sendEmail">
                <g:checkBox name="sendEmail" checked="${sendEmail == 'on'}" 
                onchange="swapFieldsets(this, '#sa-email', '#sa-password')" />
                <g:message code="onBoard.noAccessEmail" default="Send Access Email" />
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think using a hidden field would be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by javascript. Give your element an ID or hide it by name or class.

```
    document.getElementById("checkbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementsByName("checkbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

If you can use jquery this is also possible:

```
$('#checkbox').hide();
```

Take a look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp) for more information

take a look at [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_display2) to see what you want to do with your element. Then you can choose between the answers given. :)

Comment: nice answer, didnt think about the visibility thing!

Comment: Can't edit the typo: $(#'checkbox') should be $('#checkbox')

Answer (score 0):

in your style.css, add

```
.checkbox{
  display:none;
}
```

note: this will hide all elements with the class `.checkbox`, so you might want to change it (or better: give it an id)

or do it inline:

```
 <div class="checkbox" style="display:none;">
            <label for="sendEmail">
                <g:checkBox name="sendEmail" checked="${sendEmail == 'on'}" 
                onchange="swapFieldsets(this, '#sa-email', '#sa-password')" />
                <g:message code="onBoard.noAccessEmail" default="Send Access Email" />
            </label>
        </div>
```

if you want to do it in javascript, it would look like this: (you would have to give the checkbox an id)

```
document.getElementById("checkboxid").style.display = 'none';
```